# Get Latitude and Longitude values from textbox in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events

I am trying to show a google map and want to get latitude and longitude values from two textboxes. But it is not showing the google map with a marker and I want that after I enter longitude value the google map should show with the values I enter in long and latitude textboxes. I am working in wordpress

Below is my jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("#long").change(function () { 
//jQuery("div .googlemap").hide();

lat=jQuery("input #lat").val();
long=jQuery("input #long").val();

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
initialize(lat,long);
function initialize()
{
    alert("yes initialize function finally fires");
var mapProp = {
  center: myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
  title:'Click to zoom'
  });

marker.setMap(map);

// Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  map.setZoom(9);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">Latitude <input id="lat" style="height: 30px;" name="latitude" type="text" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">Longitude <input id="long" style="height: 30px;" name="longitude" type="text" /></div>
</div>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No spaces in selectors.

```
lat=jQuery("input#lat").val();
long=jQuery("input#long").val();
```

`("input #something")` means that it selects all the children, of any input, with id `#something`. If it doesn't find anything, the `.val()` returns undefined and map doesn't work.